# Oh-my-zsh Agnoster Theme font problem

Tags: command-line, themes, fonts, zsh

I installed solarized colors and also the package for coloring ls. After that I installed zsh and the framework oh-my-zsh and now my terminal looks like the following

[image]

[image]

I do have the solarized colors active, as you can see and still, in the first picture, why are those two folders highlighted in such a strange and unreadable way? and in the second picture, why are some of the gray files looking so uncrisp and blurry?

Also, I am using Inconsolata-dz for Powerline Bold as a font. What do I have to do in order to change the font to menlo?

thanks in advance

Comment: I will throw a wild guess those two folders have 777 as permission bits. Is this Gnome Terminal? (You can see in Help->About)

Comment: Indeed it is, Gnome 3.18.3     yes those two folders have full permission of all three user groups.  Do you also have an idea what is wrong with the blurry  fonts and how I install a new terminal font, if I have the otf file?

Comment: anyone?          help please

Comment: In Gnome Terminal you can click Edit-> Preferences -> Profiles and set the `Custom Font` there to whatever is installed in your system (so you just have to install a font in your system before!). You can save the profile, have multiple profiles and all... I have no idea what you mean with blurred fonts. To install fonts in your system, theoretically you just double click them in Nautilus and click install in the font thing that opens. Oh fuck, apparently [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1332426), just right click the file and use open with.

Comment: well thank you! What I mean with blurry is, if you take a look at my second screenshot you see the gray bold words are somewhat unsharp and hard to read. Thats what I was referring to

Comment: Ok, so apparently we look this website on complete different times. I had no idea what Powerline was (EE here) . The docs dont show Gnome Terminal: http://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html